# Numbers fetched after digit is 6 but i want all numbers

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am trying to fetch float numbers using rest-assured method but it is only fetching 6 digits after decimal but i have more than more than 10.

I have tried to fetch it using the code that i provided below which shows getFLoat is the method from Rest Assured library

```
JsonPath js= ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);
float latitude = js.getFloat("map.lat");
float longitude = js.getFloat("map.long");
```

This is returning me value of float as latitude = -80.375786 and longitude = 157.40535 where as in the response it is "lat": -80.375787552675078 and         "long": 157.40535607561472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, a float can only store a value up to 6-7 digits after the decimal. If you need more than that, you should be able to use double, which allows for 15-16 digits.

That being said, it looks like your code might need further changes to work as needed. I was able to get the code snippet to run locally by changing a couple things:

- Setting the JsonPath config to return numbers of type **Double**.
- Using the JsonPath **getDouble()** method for "map.lat" and "map.long".

  ```
  JsonPath js = ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);
  JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);
  double latitude = js.getDouble("map.lat");
  double longitude = js.getDouble("map.long");
  ```

After doing this, I was able to get 14 digits of precision on the decimal values you provided.

If you need more precision, you can set the config value to **JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.BIG_DECIMAL** and call **js.get("map.lat")** to return a BigDecimal object. This would give you the best precision but might be out-of-scope for your need.

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: When i used double it throwed me error as shown below: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Float cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (java.lang.Float and java.lang.Double are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') . Can you please help me here.

Comment: Are you using the getDouble method as well? For example: double latitude = js.getDouble("map.lat");

Comment: Just updated the answer after looking into the JsonPath api a bit more. Hope that works